# Azure Functions SendGrid out binding does not show in SendGrid as a message

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I am trying to use Azure Functions to send an email message through SendGrid. I have a function that has a storage queue trigger and an SendGrid output parameter. After adding a message in the queue the function runs but nothing else happens. When I login to Sendgrid it shows I have zero requests and delivered messages. Also I am not receiving any emails.

What could possibly be causing this? Is there any way to debug this further?

Here is my function code in C#:

```
public static class SendChatEmail {
    [FunctionName ("SendChatEmail")]
    public static void Run ([QueueTrigger ("decision-tree-emails", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] ChatData myQueueItem, [SendGrid (ApiKey = "SendGridApiKey")] out SendGridMessage message,
        TraceWriter log) {
        log.Info ($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

        message = new SendGridMessage ();
        message.AddTo ("matti.petrelius@gmail.com");
        message.AddContent ("text/html", "Hello there!");
        message.SetFrom (new EmailAddress ("matti.petrelius@gmail.com"));
        message.SetSubject ("Chat conversation");
    }
}
```

I'm using:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (220.0.0-beta.0)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.11651.0
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.7.1
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools - 15.0.40502.0
```

I've also tried to make a similar Function in Node.js without getting it to work any better. Maybe I'm using SendGrid somehow wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, nevermind this! Turns out the dashboard in SendGrid was just reaaaaally slow to update and did not show the requests before many hours later. So the requests were sent and delivered, the dashboard just didn't show it. Also I didn't notice receiving emails because they were directed straight to junk email! So this was a false alarm. The SendGrid binding works fine the way I did it.